# Passing model to a partial view that is used for modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open the bootstrap modal by passing the model object dynamically. The modal content is in partial view as follows,

```
@model int

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-action-id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" value="@Model" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" >cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

And, here is my div which opens modal by passing model object dynamically,

```
<div>
    @{
        for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
        {
            <div>
                <button id="deleteModal-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-sid="@i" data-target="#modal-action-id">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete @i
                </button>
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_MyPartialView", i)
            </div>

        }

    }

</div>
```

Now, the problem is no matter which button I click here it only passes the value 5 to the partial view. Also, I have only seen @await `Html.PartialAsync()` portion of code outside of for loop passing static model to the partial view in different applications. Am I missing anything here, conceptually? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is all `_MyPartialView` in same id `id="modal-action-id"`, and that's why you click any button only to show same `_MyPartialView`.

You could change button  `data-target="#modal-action-@i"`

```
<button id="deleteModal-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-sid="@i" data-target="#modal-action-@i">
```

and change  div `id="modal-action-@Model"`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-action-@Model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Then, you can get what you want. All tested.

Comment: Thank you @Michelle for the working solution. After carefully checking how partial view works with modal, It seems better to avoid this approach because it generates HtmlContent for each and every button associated with modal in the loop. And, this will cause performance problem if the loop runs for higher number of times.